# How to update flag, only if any field's of form is changed

Tags: php, yii

If any field of the form is unchanged then set flag to 1, and if any field of the form is changed then set flag to 0. Below is view:

```
<div class="row"> 
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="row"> 
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide any code that you already tried yourself

Comment: Please add the necessary code/references

Comment: @Ayush update your question.

Comment: eloborate your question

Comment: my question is, if i entered several text field while create but on update i donot change/enter any field how to change status of a column by this, if no field is changed/entered then set flag column to 0 otherwise set to 1. i think this time my question is clear.

Comment: @Ayush I think no one really not understand your question. Can you provide the model with rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Y1.1

You can do this in the model, by creating two functions function named beforeSave() and afterFind. Yii will automatically call this before saving the record, and after finding the record.

Your strategy is to make a copy of the record when you find it, and before you update it, check the current values (from the form) with the previous values.

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{  
    public $oldRecord;

    public function afterFind()
    {
        $this->oldRecord=clone $this;
        return parent::afterFind();     
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        if ($this->oldRecord->email !== $this->email) {
            $this->changed_record_flag = true;
        }    
    }

}
```